# How can i force wp-admin to use 2-column dashboard layout?

Tags: plugins, php, wp-admin, dashboard

How can i force wp-admin to use 2 column layout via plugin?

Comment: Please read [ask]. This is not a good question.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
function so_screen_layout_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['dashboard'] = 2;
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'screen_layout_columns', 'so_screen_layout_columns' );
function so_screen_layout_dashboard() {
    return 2;
}
add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard', 'so_screen_layout_dashboard' );
```

On dashboard screen options it will show 1 or 2 columns, after clicking 1 column after refresh will still be 2 columns. You can change to whatever number you want